# This is not a number error in phpMyAdmin

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am trying to create a user table this way:

[image: Table creation]

But I am getting this error:

> This is not a number

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: In My case I forgot to mention the value for attribute length/Value for datatype Varchar, then I assigned the value and it is solved.

Answer (score 9):

You need to provide the **VARCHAR** length (the number of characters). The length should be a numeric value. then you can get rid of the error.

Answer (score 4):

You're trying to create a primary key that can store an integer of length `40`.

Consult this table:

Type  | Use | Size

- TINYINT | A very small integer | The signed range is **–128 to 127**. The unsigned range is **0 to 255**.
- SMALLINT | A small integer | The signed range is **–32768 to 32767**. The unsigned range is **0 to 65535.**
- MEDIUMINT | A medium-size integer | The signed range is **–8388608 to 8388607**. The unsigned range is **0 to 16777215**
- INT or INTEGER | A normal-size integer | The signed range is **–2147483648 to 2147483647**. The unsigned range is **0 to 4294967295**
- BIGINT | A large integer | The signed range is **–9223372036854775808 to 9223372036854775807.** The unsigned range is **0 to 18446744073709551615**

As a result, PhpMyAdmin won't create the field as it exceeds the maximum allowed length for that type (INT).

http://help.scibit.com/mascon/masconMySQL_Field_Types.html

Answer (score 4):

INT type have 4 bytes storage capacity so you can only give max lenght of 11.

Check [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/integer-types.html) for more details